# HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request).toString() activates while page refresh in java

Tags: jsp, page-refresh

I have a small problem that I can't quite figure out. 
When I was looking for URL-rewriting when cookies disabled, I found this code snippet from a previous question from `stackoverflow`.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("Click <a href="
                    + response.encodeURL(HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request).toString())
                    + ">here</a>");
        }
    }
```

Instead of clicking the link, when I hit the refresh button the link automatically activated itself. Is this a functionality of `HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request)`?

Please help me to figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly see here on the XY problem:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

You can easily encode URLs within your site when cookies are not available by using the `<c:url\>` tag of the standard JSTL libraries to encode urls:

```
<c:url var="someLink" value="/somePath"/>

<a href="${someLink}">Some Link</a>
```